# How to export a jpg from ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, layouts, arcscene

How can I switch to layout view in ArcScene and export a map in jpg format?

Answer (score 6):

There is no Layout View in ArcScene.

You can export your scene to JPG by using `File` > `Export Scene` > `2D...` and selecting `JPEG` in the Save As Type drop-down of the Export Map dialog.